# mysql and python datetime

Tags: python, mysql, insert, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert records to a `mysql` database via `python` using the `sqlalchemy` package.

I have columns that are `datetime` type in mysql that already accepted data of the following format via a load table inline  command:

```
'2013-04-03 00:05:00-05:00'
```

Note this is produced by the `pytz` module in python. I had no problem loading 600,000 rows with datetime stamps with the exact same format through the mysql console using the `load table inline <file_name>` command. MySql accepts them on the load but I'm not sure if it maintains the time-zone information. It really doesn't matter to me because I have3 other columns, which represent datetimes in other time zones that I am interested in. So I know which column represents EST/EDT or CST/CDT and I can query based on that if I desire. I won't be doing any time zone conversions in mysql because I already have columns that represent the time zones of interest.

This is as per mysql's documentation:

```
The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL
retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported
range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
```

The thing is the `pytz` module provides information on the time zone in the datetime stamp that I am trying to insert. I actually have 4 columns `(EST, UTC, EST/EDT and CST/CDT)` so all have their time zone information embedded in the datetime stamp.

Note I am not using a custom `INSERT` query. This is the default way sqlalchemy performs an insert many:

The function that performs the insert looks like so:

```
def insert_data(data_2_insert, table_name):
    # Connect to database using SQLAlchemy's create_engine()
    engine = create_engine('mysql://blah:blah@localhost/db_name')
    # Metadata is a Table catalog. 
    metadata = MetaData()
    my_table = Table(table_name, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    column_names = tuple(c.name for c in my_table.c)
    final_data = [dict(zip(column_names, x)) for x in data_2_insert]
    ins = my_table.insert()
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(ins, final_data)
    conn.close()
```

The error message:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "script.py", line 191, in <module>
        main()
      File "script.py", line 39, in main
        insert_data(file_csv, table_name)
      File "script.py", line 58, in insert_data
        conn.execute(ins, final_data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 824, in execute
        return Connection.executors[c](self, object, multiparams, params)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 874, in _execute_clauseelement
        return self.__execute_context(context)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 894, in __execute_context
        self._cursor_executemany(context.cursor, context.statement, context.parameters, context=context)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 960, in _cursor_executemany
        self._handle_dbapi_exception(e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 931, in _handle_dbapi_exception
        raise exc.DBAPIError.instance(statement, parameters, e, connection_invalidated=is_disconnect)
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '2013-04-03 00:05:00-05:00' for column 'rtc_date_est' at row 1")
```

Comment: The last part seems broken: `2013-04-03 00:05:00-05:00`, there shouldn't be a `-05:00` there, right? I suppose that sqlalchemy doesn't do much type checking in this case.

Comment: Initially, my data is in `EST`. But I need that time in 2 other time zones `(EST/EDT and CST/CDT`). I don't want to perform a conversation in sql every time I need to run a date query because I will be doing that a lot. So its a storage vs performance trade off. So in python I take the datetime string, assign it to a EST time zone via `pytz.timezone('EST')` and then perform 3 conversions- to `'US/Eastern'`, `'US/Central'` and `utc`. So the `'-05:00'` is to show that it is `EST`. Similarly, `+00:00` is `UTC`, `-04:00` for `EST/EDT` and `-05:00` for `CST/CDT`.

Comment: the '-05:00' extension is present in the object that I try to insert into mysql. Note, mysql does not complain about this because I am successful via the load table. So this is a problem with sqlalchemy. How do I go about achieving my objective without re-writing my approach. I thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe I should abandon sqlalchemy and just communicate to mysql directly via mysqldb package?

Comment: No need to abandon sqlalchemy, but you do have to tell it that you want to use timestamps: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime Also, I cannot see it from the stacktrace, but is, what you are trying to insert, actually a datetime object or is it a string?

Comment: For the record, the error you're getting here comes from MySQL directly, not from SQLAlchemy :)

Comment: So the object I am inserting is a python datetime.datetime object. For example, `datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 3, 0, 5, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'EST'>)`. So its strange that MySQL gives this error on an `INSERT` but not on a `LOAD TABLE ...`.

Comment: I actually tried to set the column attribute type to DateTime(timezone=True) and then call the conn.execute(). I got the same problem.

Comment: It seems that MySQL doesn't have any timezone support in the datetime library. I think this might solve your problem though: http://mindlace.net/2012/11/13/make-datetime-naive-for-mysql-in-sqlalchemy/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that SQLAlchemy does not respect the MySQL DATETIME format.  SQLAlchemy is trying to put a timezone-aware format into MySQL DATETIME which doesn't support timezone on a per-row basis AFAIK.

The solution is to strip timezone info away from your datetime objects.  After converting them into a timezone matching your MySQL default (UTC, EST, whatever), then do the following:

```
date_value = date_value.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

where date_value is the datetime object which ends up being passed to your SQLAlchemy object.